# When do we use appium touch action and when do we use selenium touchactions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm running appium automation and my touchaction.tap from appium is sometimes failing. Should I use selenium touchactions instead? What are the differences between the two and when should I use which one?

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/touch/TouchActions.html

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is pretty simple, Selenium is used for Browser automation whereas Appium is used for Mobile app automation. Obviously, we can combine both of these frameworks too. So, it depends on your testing scenario, whether you are targetting mobile app or a web browser. If your target is testing a mobile app then you should go with Appium touch action and if your target is web browser then use Selenium touch actions.

Comment: Thanks for your response.